# How to find thresholds?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I read a MATLAB website called ["Image Processing Made Easy"](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/image-processing-made-easy-81718.html). It references [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46318-example-files-for--image-processing-made-easy--webinar):

```
rmat=Im(:,:,1);
gmat=Im(:,:,2);
bmat=Im(:,:,3);

subplot(2,2,1), imshow(rmat);
title('Red Plane');
subplot(2,2,2), imshow(gmat);
title('Green Plane');
subplot(2,2,3), imshow(bmat);
title('Blue Plane');
subplot(2,2,4), imshow(I);
title('Original Image');

%%
levelr = 0.63;
levelg = 0.5;
levelb = 0.4;
i1=im2bw(rmat,levelr);
i2=im2bw(gmat,levelg);
i3=im2bw(bmat,levelb);
Isum = (i1&i2&i3);
```

How can we find a value `levelr`, `levelg`, and `levelb`?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code. Can you share links to the website? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49322888/edit) your question.

Comment: From [this video](https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/image-processing-made-easy-81718.html) at 22:15, I think they're picked by trial and error.

Comment: @Steve I'm inclined to agree.  It looks like they've picked values that would work for this particular image, but this by no means generalizes to all images.

Comment: so that is not a mean of rmat, right ?

Comment: People do research on finding those values, its really hard. For a starter level: just pick one until it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of late, but I've found that the built-in MATLAB function graythresh() works pretty well. It relies on Otsu's Method (pretty well-known, described in the documentation) and does well with imbinarize/im2bw.

eg,

```
levelr = graythresh(rmat)
```

and `levelr` will be a threshold between 0 - 1.0

Comment: @PutriRanati consider accepting the answer as correct if it did help you